# Integrating over measures on product measurable spaces that are not necessarily product measures

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to get to grips with measures that are defined on product $\sigma$-algebras but which are not necessarily product measures. I know that one can integrate against such a measure in the same way as any other measure, but my intuition is that there is also a way to think about "integrating over each variable separately" (and hopefully show that it gives the same answer). This question is about whether such a concept really exists, and if so, understanding the details.

Let $(X,\Sigma_X)$ and $(Y,\Sigma_Y)$ be measurable spaces, and consider $X\otimes Y$ = $(X\times Y, \Sigma_X\otimes \Sigma_Y)$, where $\Sigma_X\otimes \Sigma_Y$ is the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Then let $\nu$ be a measure on $X\otimes Y$ (say a probability measure) and let $f\colon X\times Y\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function (say a bounded one).

Now suppose I want to integrate $f$ against $\nu$. One way to do this is to just treat $X\otimes Y$ the same as any other measurable space, and integrate over all its measurable subsets. I could write this as something like

$$
\int_{(x,y)\in X\otimes Y} f(x,y)\,\nu(d(x,y)),
$$
where the awkward $d(x,y)$ is meant to indicate that we're integrating over arbitrary measurable subsets of $X\otimes Y$.

However, I think it would be more natural to write this as
$$
\int_{x\in X, y\in Y} f(x,y) \,\nu(dx\times dy),
$$
and I have seen things like this written down before.

This notation suggests that we are somehow integrating not over all measurable subsets of $X\otimes Y$ but only those of the form $S\times T$ for $S\in\Sigma_X$ and $T\in\Sigma_Y$. It feels intuitively that that should be possible (perhaps something to do with Carathéodory's extension theorem?), but I am not at all sure of the details.

So my question is, how should I correctly conceptualise integrating over a measure on a product of measurable spaces that is not necessarily a product measure? What does integrating over $dx\times dy$ really mean, and more importantly, how do I formally manipulate integrals of this form?

Pointers to resources that cover this stuff are welcome, in addition to explanations in the answers.

**Edit:** I think my question was not precise enough. Maybe the following gives a better idea of what I'm grasping for.

Let's suppose that the function $f$ is of the form $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$, with $g$ and $h$ both bounded. Then, intuitively, I think I can split this up into a double integral,
$$
\int_{x\in X}g(x)\int_{y\in Y}h(y)\,\nu(dx\times dy).
$$
Note that this is not an instance of Fubini's theorem, because $\nu$ isn't a product measure.

The meaning of this is as follows: if $S\in\Sigma_X$ is some fixed measurable subset of $X$, then $\nu(S\times {-})$ forms a measure over $Y$ (a subprobability measure in fact, if $\nu$ is a probability measure). Then, for a fixed $x\in X$,
$$
\int_{y\in Y} h(y)\,\nu(S\times dy)
$$
means the integration of this subprobability measure against the function $h\colon Y\to\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure, but I think if we then regard this as a function of $S$, then it forms a measure on $X$. (This time a finite measure, not necessarily a subprobability measure.) Certainly it forms a measure when $h(y)$ is the indicator function for some $T\in \Sigma_Y$, and I'm guessing that means it's a measure in general.

Then the double integral above refers to integrating this measure against the measurable function $g\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$.

Then I hypothesise that
$$
\int_{(x,y)\in X\otimes Y} g(x)h(y) \,\nu(d(x,y)) = \int_{x\in X}g(x)\int_{y\in Y}h(y)\,\nu(dx\times dy),
$$
with the right-hand side interpreted how I just described.

If so this would be a case in which the $dx\times dy$ notation "means something", instead of just being notation for integrating over $X\otimes Y$.

As a supplementary question I'd like to know if this is correct, but my main question is still whether it makes sense to think about "integrating over rectangles" in general, and if so how to correctly reason about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Added:** The question was clarified a lot, to the point that this answer is mostly obsolete. I'll leave it here because I think the discussion between myself and the OP in the comments can add additional useful context for future visitors to this page.

---

*Old answer:* If $X$ and $Y$ are measurable spaces, then we can form $X\times Y$ with the product $\sigma$-algebra, as you say. If $\nu$ is a measure on $X\times Y$, then $\int f\,d\nu$ has a perfectly well defined meaning regardless of the notation we use. That's because we know the $\nu$-measure of all the elements of $\Sigma_X\otimes\Sigma_Y$ by definition of $\nu$. Therefore, we know what it means to integrate a simple function $\phi(x,y) = \sum_i c_i\chi_{E_i}(x,y)$ with respect to $\nu$. As long as we know what it means to integrate simple functions, extending the definition of integration of arbitrary functions follows from the usual approximation procedure of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Thank you. I think my question wasn't clear enough - I know that I can just treat $X\otimes Y$ as a measurable space like any other, but my intuition is that it *also* makes sense to consider integrating over $X$ and $Y$ separately (and hopefully show that they give the same answer). I'd added an addendum to my question that might or might not make it clearer what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: @N.Virgo: I see. I think in general, the answer is going to be "no" because if all we are given is a measure $\nu$, $\nu$ doesn't have any special structure, so if we restrict $\nu$ to the slices $\{x\}\times Y$ (say), then $\nu(E)$ could be zero for every $E\subset\{x\}\times Y$. You may be interested to read about "disintegration" which gives a somewhat general setup and necessary conditions to integrate a non-product measure with some extra structure in a fiber-wise way.